# Cursor - Toshiba satellite - windows 8

Tags: toshiba-laptop

My cursor isn't moving, I've tried the f5 key but it does nothing, the only way I can move my mouse is by holding down one of the buttons on the touchpad. I've tried restarting my computer, even taking out the battery- nothing seems to fix it. Help?

Answer (score 0):

Check the to see if Windows downloaded and updated any drivers recently.  I seen another user say it was "Synaptics Pointing Device Driver" in Programs and Features.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)